# JQuery Data Formatting in .each loop

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I have dynamic amount of `div` that needs to be formatted into data stored in database. Each of the `div` format is this:

```
<div class="spec-list-row row row-5">
                        <input type="text" class="spec_name" placeholder="nama spec" />
                        <input type="text" class="spec_value" placeholder="isi spec" />
                    </div>
```

On submit, each of the `spec-list-row` data SHOULD be formatted like this (if there are 2 `spec-list-row`):

`{"spec_name_1":"spec_value_1","spec_value_2":"spec_value_2"}`

instead, it is formatted like this:

`{"spec_name_1":"spec_value_1","spec_value_2":"spec_value_2",}
{"spec_name_1":"spec_value_1","spec_value_2":"spec_value_2",}`

My code to generate the data is this (in coffeescript):

```
spec_str += "{"

            $("div.spec-list-row").each ->
                spec_str += '"' +  $(this).find("input.spec_name").val() + '":"' + $(this).find("input.spec_value").val() + ","

            spec_str += "}"
```

**EDIT**

I solved it by changing my code to this:

```
$("button[add-product]").click (e) ->
    error = false

    $("form#add-product-form input[required]").each ->
        if $(this).val() is null or $(this).val() is ""
            alert "* needs to be filled"
            error = true
            false

    unless processing
        if not error
            e.preventDefault()
            processing = true

                    ### solution from here ###
            specObj = new Object()

            $("div.spec-list-row").each ->
                specObj[$(this).find("input.spec_name").val()] = $(this).find("input.spec_value").val()

            spec_str = JSON.stringify specObj
                    ### to here ###

            fd = new FormData()
            fd.append "image", image_file
            fd.append "data", $("form#add-product-form").serialize()
            fd.append "specs", spec_str

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST'
                processData: false
                contentType: false
                data: fd
                url: base_link+'add_product'
                cache: false
                timeout: 15000
            }).done (msg) ->
                alert msg
                processing = false
            .fail (res) ->
                alert res.responseText
                processing = false
```

Thank you for the comment, it gives me a hint (even though i find it harsh, pretty sure it was for my good cause).

Comment: This is all wrong. One *never* builds JSON from bits of string. In fact in this case you don't need to create JSON *at all*. Create an object, post that to the server. jQuery does all the encoding for you. (Hint: Maybe it's too early to jump on CoffeeScript when you're still struggling with the very basics of the underlying environment)

Comment: @Tomalak: if you are referring to `serialize`, yes I am familiar with that. All other data in the form is serialized and posted to the server using formdata. Only that this data cannot be `serialize` (or I don't know how to), since the number of `spec-list-row` is not determined (it might be null). Just to make it clear: `spec-list-row` is NOT the only data in the form, it is one of the data in the form, then the form is serialized and sent. My real problem is how to read an undetermined number of object later at the server, so I convert is to string.

Comment: I don't refer to `$.serialize()`. That works for form fields only anyway. I refer to a plain old JavaScript object that you `$.post()` to the server as is. jQuery will do the JSON conversion transparently. You just need to build the desired JS object.